# Clarification on Searle's method to determine thermal conductivity

Tags: thermodynamics, thermal-conductivity

[image]

Here In Searle's method to determine the thermal conductivity of a good conductor, the heat transfer rate of the conductor along a  displacement(thickness) *d* is given by:

Q<sub>1</sub>/t=KD(T<sub>1</sub>-T<sub>2</sub>)/d.

=>Q<sub>1</sub>=KD(T<sub>1</sub>-T<sub>2</sub>)t/d

And the heat transferred to the cold water is given by:

Q<sub>2</sub>=mS(T<sub>3</sub>-T<sub>4</sub>)

I can follow up to this point, but my problem arises when it’s said that,

Q<sub>1</sub>=Q<sub>2</sub>

My argument is that, Q<sub>1</sub> is the heat transferred along the *d* displacement, not the entire rod. If T<sub>1</sub> and T<sub>2</sub> was placed at the beginning and end of the rod respectively, only then we could say Q<sub>1</sub>=Q<sub>2</sub>. But this is not specified. All the sources say that *d* can be *any known distance on the rod*. But clearly anything other than *d*=**the entire length of the rod** wouldn't give the correct value, right? Should this clarification be made?

Comment: You seem to be very confused.  At steady state, the rate of heat flow down the rod is constant (up to location 3).  If d gets larger, then the temperature difference T1-T2 also gets larger in proportion.  So the ratio of T1-T2 to the distance d is a constant.  In the experiment, it is assumed that all the heat reaching location 3 enters the circulating water and heats this water up to T4.  So the rate of heat removal by the water, as determined by T4-T3, is equal to Q=Q1=Q2.

Comment: you mean Q1=KD(T1-T2)/d is the same for any *d* on the length of the rod?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I mean.

Comment: I'm sorry for not following on. But why is this Q1 constant?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider a proof by contradiction: $Q_1\neq Q_2$, such that $Q_1=Q_2+Q_3$, where $Q_3$ must be stored on the right side of the rod. (We can show this with an energy balance of the right side of the rod.) We consider the sensible heating of that region: $Q_3=mc\frac{dT}{dt}$, where $m$ is the mass, $c$ is the specific heat capacity, $T$, is the temperature, and $t$ is time. At steady state, the temperature must be constant ($\frac{dT}{dt}=0$), so $Q_3=0$ and we have in fact $Q_1=Q_2$.

Comment: Could you simplify it a little bit? I'm not really that knowledgeable in this field.

Comment: Sure! In plainer language, the heat flux in must equal the heat flux out, or energy would be stored or depleted within the rod. This would change its temperature over time. But Searle's method depends on the device conducting heat at steady state, meaning all temperatures remain constant. (In practice, the operator would wait until all temperatures settle to constant values before starting the experiment.) So we can exclude the possibility that $Q_1$ is different from $Q_2$. Hope this clarifies.

Comment: I still don't understand why Q3=0.

Comment: You could think of it this way: if you pump water through a pipe, why is the inlet flow the same as the outlet flow? Why can't they differ?

Comment: Ok the rate might be the same. But why would the amount be the same? I agree that the rate at which heat flows throughout the rod might be the same. But wouldn't the amount of heat transferred increase with thickness *d*?

Comment: When two rates are identical and a single duration is used, what other possibility is there?

Comment: And here in Q3, *dT* is equal to T4-T3. According to you, T4-T3=0 => T4=T3. How did we reach this conclusion?

Comment: $dT$ is not equal to $T_4$-$T_3$. That's a spatial temperature difference, whereas $\frac{dT}{dt}$ is the rate of temperature change in a certain location—a temporal temperature difference.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/135946/discussion-between-chemomechanics-and-acrafi).